# install ubuntu sdk error

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

I have this error:

```
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20130820.1)/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch bzip2:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/jo.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not an error, the "W" is a warning.

This message can be ignored, it is telling you Ubuntu is looking for packages on the "cdrom", but there is no cdrom on your system.

Remove (uncheck) the CDROM from your sources:

[image]

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu for additional information.

Comment: it is unchecked

Comment: OK, try `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: i tried it & i have the same warning

Comment: Post the exact output you are getting as well as your sources. The second warning usually comes from connectivity problems, try another mirror or try again later today.